# Using method name "x" with implicit conversions in Scala

Tags: scala, compilation, implicit-conversion

Suppose I want to add a facility for computing the vector product of two 3-tuples by providing an implicit conversion like this:

```scala
import scala.math.Numeric.Implicits._

case class Vector3[T : Numeric](a : T, b : T, c : T) {
    def x(v : Vector3[T]) = (b*v.c - c*v.b, c*v.a - a*v.c, a*v.b - b*v.a)
}

implicit def toVector[T : Numeric](p : (T,T,T)) = Vector3(p._1, p._2, p._3)
```

I would expect the following peace of code to compile:

```
       (1,0,0) x (0,1,0) // does not compile
```

However, it yields an error, that "x" is not a member of (Int, Int, Int).
Creating an instance of the wrapper class by hand works:

```
Vector3(1,0,0) x (0,1,0) // compiles
```

If I use another method name instead of 'x', say, 'y', the implicit conversion also works:

```
       (1,0,0) y (0,1,0) // compiles
Vector3(1,0,0) y (0,1,0) // compiles
```

What is so special about "x"? And how does it interfere with the implicit conversion mechanism?

Comment: This looks a lot like [my favorite Scala bug of all time](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/399ab16c296021de8fff1f0dd234f5f21230e82e/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L277), but I thought that was fixed a long time ago, and I just confirmed what you're seeing on 2.11.5, so I have no idea.

Comment: @TravisBrown - You don't think that when that _one_ bug was fixed every _similar_ bug was fixed, do you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is wrong with `.x`?  Let's ask:

```
scala> (1,2,3).x
<console>:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int, Int)
 required: ?{def x: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable
because they are ambiguous:
 both method tuple3ToZippedOps in object Predef of type
   [T1, T2, T3](x: (T1, T2, T3))runtime.Tuple3Zipped.Ops[T1,T2,T3]
 and method toVector of type
   [T](p: (T, T, T))(implicit evidence$1: Numeric[T])Vector3[T]
 are possible conversion functions from (Int, Int, Int) to ?{def x: ?}
```

So you see the problem: `x` was used as the name for the underlying tuple in another conversion.  Here it is from `runtime.Tuple3Zipped.Ops`:

```
final class Ops[T1, T2, T3](val x: (T1, T2, T3)) extends AnyVal
```

It's arguably a bug; the `x` is a nuisance parameter, and the convention is to call it `repr` or `underlying`, and in 2.11 it can be made private so as not to bother anyone.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. The compiler error message is somehow misleading  when passing an argument to "x". Do you have any suggestion what would be an idiomatic way to name such an operator when the natural name is already "occupied"?

Comment: You could use a different character that looks similar, e.g. "×". In this specific case that's even a "more correct" symbol for the operation in question.